# How to iterate nested dictionary and get all values of one entity

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Data={
    0:{
        'name': "John",
        'country': "xyz",
        'country_id': "0",
        'event_dict': {
           0: {
               'event1': "T",
               'event_no': "45",
               'event_id': "01"
           },
           1: {
               'event1': "C",
               'event_no': "32",
               'event_id': "T",
           },    
           2: {
              'event1': "B",
              'event_no': "11",
              'event_id': "s",
           },    
           3: {
              'event1': "A",
              'event_no': "0",
              'event_id':"p",
           }
        },      
    },    
   1:{        
       'name': "Henry",
       'country': "",
       'country_id': "1",    
       'event_dict': {
           0:{
              'event1': "no",
              'event_no': "23",
              'event_id':"abc"
           },
           1: {
              'event1': "yes",
              'event_no': "8",
              'event_id':"def",
           },    
           2: {
              'event1': "false",
              'event_no': "",
              'event_id': "ghi",
           },    
           3: {
              'event1': "NA",
              'event_no': "9",
              'event_id': "jkl", 
           }
        },
    },
}
```

I am unable to iterate over the nested dictionary to get all the values of `event_id` for `event_dict` `[0,1,2,3]` for each `Data[0 and 1]`. How to get all the values of `['event_id']`?

Comment: Can you write which type of output you want?

Comment: @Mithel why can't you loop through and append the values to a list?

Comment: @Hiral Talsaniya  Thank you. I got the solution for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for k1,v1 in Data.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1['event_dict'].items():
        print(f"{k1}->{k2}-> event_id : {v2['event_id']}")
```

---

```
0->0-> event_id : 01
0->1-> event_id : T
0->2-> event_id : s
0->3-> event_id : p
1->0-> event_id : abc
1->1-> event_id : def
1->2-> event_id : ghi
1->3-> event_id : jkl
```

**Update:** Store in a list.

```
ids = [v2['event_id'] 
       for k1,v1 in Data.items() 
       for k2, v2 in v1['event_dict'].items()]
print(ids)
# ['01', 'T', 's', 'p', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works however I want to store it in list format. Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I got the desired result.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I missed to check your answer. But I accepted your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code if you want the list of event_id

```
[v2['event_id'] for k1, v1 in Data.items() for k2, v2 in v1['event_dict'].items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist=[] 
for k1,v1 in Data.items():
    print('MAIN entity:',k1)
    for k2,v2 in Data[k1].items():
         if k2=='event_dict':
            # print(k2,v2)
            for k3,v3 in Data[k1][k2].items():
                print(k3,v3['event_id']) 
                
print("-------------------OR-------------")    
for k1,v1 in Data.items():
    
    for k2,v2 in Data[k1].items():
         if k2=='event_dict':
            # print(k2,v2)
            for k3,v3 in Data[k1][k2].items():
                print(v3['event_id'],sep=" ",) 
                mylist.append(v3['event_id'])
    print(mylist)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].